# R Psych package: multi histogram labels by variable

Tags: r, psych

I am ploting a multiple histogram for 5 variables, and I have the same title repeated along all of them. I didn´t find a way to personalize it for each histogram. Is there a way to do it? I am using the psych R package.
Maybe another package to recommend?

The code line:

```
multi.hist(AutosCompleteNorm[,11:15],main="bah")
```

And "bah" is repeated 5 times. I tried c("a","b",..."e") as an argument but it didn´t work.

Package documentation:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/1.8.3.3/topics/multi.hist

Thanks!

Comment: Don’t believe r ever use c[] (square bracket), the standard is c() to concatenate.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo but the code was ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current `psych` package doesn't seem to support this, which is strange because it would have been a natural feature for such a plot.

For customizability, I recommend you to take a look at `ggplot` and then layout in the format you wish using `gridExtra`.

Here's the code to create the few histogram in `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(vids, aes(x=log(likes)))+geom_histogram()+labs(title="title1")
p2 <- ggplot(vids, aes(x=log(dislikes)))+geom_histogram()+labs(title="title2")
p3 <- ggplot(vids, 
aes(x=log(comment_count)))+geom_histogram()+labs(title="title3")
```

And then laying them up in a 2 row layout (`nrow=2`):

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Changing the layout to `nrow=1`:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Following these comments, I just updated psych so that multi.hist is more useful.

You can now specify the margins for the plots, and it will, by default label each plot with the variable name.

I have not pushed the development version of psych (1.8.9) to CRAN yet, but it is available on my repository at

```
install.packages("psych",repos="https://personality-project.org/r",type="source")
```